# Limited number of displays (figure + table) according to the journal

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I just wonder according to Nature journal, we are allow to have 6 displays including figures and tables. However, my paper has 8 displays (1 table + 7 figures). Is that fine to have 8 displays for an initial submission?

Comment: Contact the journal.

Answer (score 1):

The number of display items in a paper is so easy to modulate that there is really no good reason *not* to comply with a journal's requirements, even on initial submission.

If you have too many display items for their preference, you can easily reduce the number without reducing the actual content by these two techniques:

1. Turn figures into sub-figures in a multi-part figure.  Most papers in figure-limited journals (including Nature and Science) have multiple sub-figures inside of them---sometimes *many* panels taking up a whole page with small images and graphs!
2. Move some figures to supplementary information.  Journals that require "short-form" papers (including Nature and Science) typically have large amounts of supplementary information, including figures, associated with each article.

If you don't comply with the formatting instructions, you risk rejection without review.  Maybe it's only a slight risk, but since these techniques make compliance easy, why bother to take that risk?

Comment: Thanks @jakebeal, I just wonder since my supervisor said don't worry about that, I am too worried to take the risk. By the way, he is a well-known scientist in the field.

Comment: @user2842390 Personally, I'd still probably do the easy thing and change the figure out.  If your advisor has a lot of experience with the particular journal (and specific editor!), then they're probably not wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with other journals published by Nature Research is that they will have an editorial assistant check for rule adherence before forwarding it on to the editor. I find it hard to believe that Nature wouldn't be at least as strict on this front, so most likely you'd be told to reformat your initial submission.

Contact the journal before submission if you want to try to get an exception. However, your research probably has to be something quite special for Nature of all journals to make such exceptions. Other options are to include multiple figures into a single display panel, or to make use of what Nature calls "extended data figures". [These](https://www.nature.com/documents/nature-paper-composition.pdf) are not shown in the print paper, but can be referenced in the text, and are included at the end of the online/PDF versions.

Comment: Thanks Anyon, yeah, they should ask, I wish they do. I'm worried to take the risk although my supervisor said don't worry about that ???!!!!